# Finder column view modify width of active column

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, applescript, finder

Is there a way in any language written for OSX (Applescript, C++, etc.) where
I can access the function (adjust column width) in the context menu, when you right 
click on the two lines at the bottom of the Scrollbar in Finders Column 
View (AXMenu->AXMenuItem)?
Same happens if you double click on the two lines.

Because what I want to do is somehow get a shortcut on this function for "super-fast-
finder-workflows".

Answer (score 0):

From the Finder Applescript Library:

```
column view options: the column view options
properties
    text size (integer) : the size of the text displayed in the column view
    shows icon (boolean) : displays an icon next to the label in column view
    shows icon preview (boolean) : displays a preview of the item in column view
    shows preview column (boolean) : displays the preview column in column view
    discloses preview pane (boolean) : discloses the preview pane of the preview column in column view
```

It doesn't look like Applescript contains a way to access the settings you are looking for